# How to get Facebook token version 1.0? [AFTER APRIL 30TH 2015]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get Facebook token Version 1.0 for additional function like following : `post` and `search` functions. But Facebook not providing any of  Token version 1.0 Based on this source: [Devs Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0?__mref=message_bubble)

In other words  by now we cant do post and search using Facebook Token version  > 2.0. So anyone had any idea about this? Thank you so much !

Please read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation) first before -1 vote. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

the API 1.0 is basically deprecated now, because even if you try to use it, your app still need to follow the new politics of the login review. So, get it reviewed to be able to use any extended permission from now on.(it's what we are doing at my job after days of research...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i don't have any of version 1 atm